# How to add multi-language support in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I obtain data written in several languages from database and show it in silverlight datagrid, but all the non-latin symbols (e.g. Russian, French, German) is displayed as '?'. How can i resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you store your data in database as 'text' or 'varchar'. If that is true than change type to 'ntext' or 'nvarchar'.